# how to use -ss and -itsoffset together to precisely delay input start time?

Tags: ffmpeg

I am rendering a `-filter_complex` output that has two input videos that are trimmed, and start at various times in the output video. The command looks like this:

```bash
ffmpeg \
  -ss 234 -itsoffset 3.5 -t 3 -i video_01.mp4 \
  -ss 23 -itsoffset 3.5 -t 3 -i video_02.mp4 \
  -ss 3 -itsoffset 5 -t 5 -i video_03.mp4 \
  -filter_complex 'color=s=1280x720:color=black:duration=10[base];
[base][0:v]overlay[v_out_0];
[v_out_0][1:v]overlay=x=main_w - 640[out]' \
  -map '[out]' \
  output.mp4
```

What this command should do, is start video_01.mp4 and video_02.mp4 at 00:00:03.5, and video_03.mp4 at 00:00:05. What actually happens is that video_01.mp4 and video_02.mp4 start at *roughly* 00:00:03.5, but one appears after the other several hundred milliseconds later. I know this has to do with combining `-ss` with `-itsoffset` because the videos start at exactly the right time if I remove `-ss` from the above command.

I have heard that `-copyts -vsync 0` is the solution, but the following command (which adds those args) creates an output that includes all of the input's timestamp. E.g. if video_01.mp4 is a 3 minute video, despite the command appearing to render a 10 second video, the output is 3 minutes. The output is also not playable on vlc or mpv.

```bash
ffmpeg \
  -ss 234 -copyts -vsync 0 -itsoffset 3.5 -t 3 -i video_01.mp4 \
  -ss 23 -copyts -vsync 0 -itsoffset 3.5 -t 3 -i video_02.mp4 \
  -ss 3 -copyts -vsync 0 -itsoffset 5 -t 5 -i video_03.mp4 \
  -filter_complex 'color=s=1280x720:color=black:duration=10[base];
[base][0:v]overlay[v_out_0];
[v_out_0][1:v]overlay=x=main_w - 640[out]' \
  -map '[out]' \
  output.mp4
```

How can I offset ffmpeg inputs in a precise way using `-itsoffset`?

(side note: I have succeeded offsetting inputs precisely with `setpts`, but this is slower, probably because it has to rewrite each timestamp)